# How to fix 'Tuple' object does not support item assignment problem in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I'm building a merge sorter from scratch because I was interested in how it works, but I'm running into a tuple problem. What does this mean and how do I fix it?

I recently started learning Python 3 with basic tutorials and solving simple problems.

```
def MergeSort(alist):
    if len(alist)>1:
        mid = len(alist)//2
        leftHalf = alist[:mid]
        rightHalf = alist[mid:]

        MergeSort(leftHalf)
        MergeSort(rightHalf)
        i = 0
        j = 0
        k = 0
        while i<len(leftHalf) and j<len(rightHalf):
            if(leftHalf[i] < rightHalf[j]):
                alist[k] = rightHalf[i]
                i+= 1
            else:
                alist[k] = rightHalf[j]
                j += 1 
            k += 1

        while i<len(leftHalf):
            alist[k] = leftHalf[i]
            i += 1 
            k += 1 

        while j<len(rightHalf):
            alist[k] = rightHalf[j]
            j+= 1 
            k+= 1 
alist = (343, 543653, 643, -543, 534, -543234, 5432, 1232)
MergeSort(alist)
print(alist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are immutable in Python. You should make `aList` a list instead to allow mutation:

```
alist = [343, 543653, 643, -543, 534, -543234, 5432, 1232]
```